# KeyError while formatting

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a list which is extracted from a json file containing multiple lists. I use a function to extract it and convert it into a list which works well.

The list is a Telegram inline keyboard which needs to be formatted before being use as an output, in case lists can't be formatted, I'm converting the list into a string, then formatting it and then I turn it back into list by json.load

```
x = keyboards.getKeyboard('example1')
d = str(x)
y = d.format(var1 = 'Do')
```

an example of what x is:

```
{"inline_keyboard": [[{"callback_data": "sure ban {var1}", "text": "Ban"}]]}
```

so, when I run the code, I get following error which happens which formatting the text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Mohammad\ide-latest-released\eclipse\dropins\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.4.0.201611281236\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1537, in <module>
globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
File "C:\Users\Mohammad\ide-latest-released\eclipse\dropins\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.4.0.201611281236\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 976, in run
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
File "C:\Users\Mohammad\ide-latest-released\eclipse\dropins\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.4.0.201611281236\pysrc\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "C:\Users\Mohammad\new_workspace\Palaton 2.0.1\palaton\qtest.py", line 6, in <module>
d.format(2)
KeyError: '"inline_keyboard"
```

I tried using dumps but I didn't get any result from that either.
Any other way to handle dynamic lists? I'm trying to figure out why the error is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: You can't use formatting on a string representation of a dictionary; dictionary syntax **also** uses `{...}` curly braces. You have a `{"inline_keyboard"...}` slot in that format.

Comment: Why are you not just using formatting on the actual strings in the dictionary?

Comment: Thanks for explaining the error. @MartijnPieters what's inside the dictionary isn't static either,  so I guess I only can format it when I know exactly where to find my string, is that correct?

Comment: Correct; just recurse over the dictionary and apply string formatting to string objects you find.

Comment: Related: [Max string recursion exceeded when using str.format\_map()](//stackoverflow.com/q/41738604)